How do you cover the whole building with curtains, randomly
During the construction of the building, I completed the curtain part. This building has more than 20 floors, now I need some help.
How can I quickly paste the curtain part using the script?
I've got three or four curtains all over the building, what if we randomize some curtains? I tried to use the modifier, but after the application of the modifier still needs a lot of tedious things, so I came to ask for help


Hello, LIN.. welcome. Sure, we can answer this in principle, but..there's nearly always a catch :) .. If you share a representative file on https://blend-exchange.com/ , we can be sure our answers actually work.

I am very sorry that it is the first time for me to look for the answer here, because it is an internal document, so I made another simple document, I hope you can understand, I will be very grateful to you

OK, I will not say any more nonsense, back to the topic, now I have to copy and use the modifier to put these curtains. What I want is to extract three or four different curtains from the existing curtains, and then use python scripts to quickly arrange these curtains at will.

In this way, it is convenient for me to modify or make materials later, so as not to repeat some useless work. I have uploaded this file. Can you help me to see if there is any good way to help me

Among them, the empty is the window, because the file is too large so I deleted it, if some do not understand you can ask me, I also want to solve the problem as soon as possible, thank you bro

Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Thank you for reminding me, this link is not important, I re-made a relatively simple file, in order to help my friends to understand my problem
